# Invoke classes with Class.forName

Tags: java, android, class

I'm following a tutorial, and I face an error; according to the tutorial the code below must work and invoke the `activity` `StartingPoint`. However, it doesn't.
I simplified the code and just invoke the `activity` no matter what, and it's working, so I just copy these two. Would you please check them?

Not working :

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity{

String classes[] = { "StartingPoint", "example1", "example2"
        , "example3", "example4", "example5", "example6"};  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.thenewboston.travis." + cheese);        
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

This code works fine, so other parts of the project is just fine:

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity{

String classes[] = { "StartingPoint", "example1", "example2"
        , "example3", "example4", "example5", "example6"};  

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent("com.thenewboston.travis.STARTINGPOINT");
    startActivity(ourIntent);
 }
}
```

I have a P.S. Here too :)
In the second code I have used capital 'STARTINGPOINT' to invoke the `activity`, however, in the original tutorial he used 'StartingPoint', and append this to the name of the class, how does it work?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
          <activity
        android:name=".StartingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.thenewboston.travis.STARTINGPOINT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.thenewboston.travis.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. I used a different package name.
in the beginning of the project I chose `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.thenewboston"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >`

until this point non of the `Intent` caused no error, but I guess when I was using `Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.thenewboston.travis." + cheese);`
This would go and search in the package, but my package name was `com.example.thenewboston`, so I guess it is searching inside the package for a class.
Anyway, after changing everything and moving files to a new package, everything worked!
However, I still don't know why I need not to use capital STARTINGPOINT and StartingPoint is still working. I have a guess, I think it is not looking into the manifest, but it's looking java files, and the name of the file is important. Anyway, I'm a newbie, I'm just guessing. :)

Answer (score 1):

the first example uses reflection, to retrieve the class object which represents the `Activity` you want to start. In the second you are using an action to start the next activity. Open your `AndroidManifest.xml` and look for `com.thenewboston.travis.STARTINGPOINT`, you will find an action associated with an `Activity`

Edit

```
"example1", "example2"
        , "example3", "example4", "example5", "example6"
```

have to be `Activitiy` subclass and have to be declared on the AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: with `com.thenewboston.travis.STARTINGPOINT` you will start StartingPoint

Comment: does `example1 extend Activity` ?

Comment: No. Just the StartingPoint has an activity associated with it. I added the Manifest to the question. It's just a menu, a welcome screen, and StartingPoint.

Comment: than you can't use `startActivity` with `example1.class`. `startActivity` is only for classes that `extend Activity`

Comment: OK, startingpoint is an activity, the rest were just dummies, so I can see them in menu. However, I still didn't understand why the the first code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set class name string using `Intent` SetClass() :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName(Menu.this, "com.thenewboston.travis." + cheese);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I am trying to learn for now, so I'm trying to figure out the problem. I think you solution would work, but I guess, it wouldn't work, since I already checked that StartingPoint is not working and all of the letters must be capital, I don't know why though. I added the manifest to the question. Then again, in tutorial, everything works fine even when in manifest action name is all capital too.